# How can I use Insert in tearadata with if and else condition?

Tags: if-statement, teradata

I want to insert data in a table like

```
if(a<> b and a<>c)
insert into table (a)
(b)
(c)
else if (a<>b and a=c)
insert into table (a) 
(b)
else insert (a)
end if
```

Comment: and what's stops you from doing that? please elaborate

Comment: Is the target always the same table?

Comment: what is a, b, c in if and else conditions? table names?